# How to differentiate stop-limit orders from limit orders using list orders on Coinbase Pro API

Tags: coinbase-api

When placing a new order using the Coinbase Pro api using the following payload:

```
{
 "size":"0.001",
 "side":"sell",
 "product_id":"BTC-EUR",
 "type": "limit",
 "price":"49999",
 "stop":"loss",
 "stop_price":"50000"
}
```

I place a stop-loss-limit order on the exchange.

When listing my current open orders, I get the following back:

```
{
 "id":"XXXXXXXXXX",
 "price":"49999.00000000",
 "size":"0.00100000",
 "product_id":"BTC-EUR",
 "profile_id":"XXXXXXXXXX",
 "side":"sell",
 "type":"limit",
 "time_in_force":"GTC",
 "post_only":false,
 "created_at":"2021-08-31T08:04:33.731426Z",
 "fill_fees":"0.0000000000000000",
 "filled_size":"0.00000000",
 "executed_value":"0.0000000000000000",
 "status":"open",
 "settled":false
}
```

In the open orders array, there is no indication whether that given order is a stop-loss-limit order or not. According to the documentation, I would expect to have Stop specific fields like *stop* or *stop_price*. Is there any way to get this information from this endpoint? Thanks!